# Is a lambda an atom in the book "the little schemer"?

Tags: lambda, the-little-schemer

I'm reading the 10th chapter of the book "The little schemer - 4th edition", which implements a simple schemer interpreter. All the other content is fine to me, except the function `:atom?` in Page 188:

```
(define :atom?
  (lambda (x)
    (cond
      ((atom? x) #t)
      ((null? x) #f)
      ((eq? (car x) (quote primitive)) #t)
      ((eq? (car x) (quote non-primitive) #t)
      (else #f)))))
```

I'm not clear about this line:

```
((eq? (car x) (quote non-primitive) #t)
```

From the previous of the book, the `non-primitive` is corresponding to a lambda definition.

```
(lambda (x) (+ x 1))
```

has the value of (with the passing environment `table`):

```
(non-primitive (table (x) (+ x 1)))
```

Does this mean a lambda definition is an `atom`, in the book?

I guess it is but not quite sure about it since I can't find their relationship mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))` would not be an atom, but the evaluated value which results in a closure should be identified by the evaluator as an atom.

In lisps everything that is not a a list is an atom. You could define it like this:

```
(define atom?
  (lambda (x)
    (not (or (null? x)
             (pair? x)))))
```

Now if you modeled your closures as `pairs` with first element as a tag identifying it as such you need to make sure those evaluates as atomic too and that's what your `:atom?` does by looking for `primitive` and `non-primitive`